# No record in data base after submit form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a problem with my form, when I click on send, nothing is saved in the database with PDO statement.
I do not know why but, I suspect syntax of the request which poses problem?
Could someone help me to find out why?

Thank you.

```
<?php 

$dbHost = "localhost";
$dbUser = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbName = "contactfrom";

try {
  $dsn = "mysql:host=" . $dbHost . ";dbname=" . $dbName;
  $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $dbUser, $dbPassword);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "DB Connection Failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}


$status = "";
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];

  if(empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($message)) {
    $status = "Tous les champs sont obligatoires.";
  } else {
    if(strlen($name) >= 255 || !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-'\s]+$/", $name)) {
      $status = "Ajoutez un nom";
    } else if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $status = "Ajouter un email valide";
    } else {

    var_dump($_POST);

      $sql = "INSERT INTO contact (name, email, message) VALUES (:name, :email, :message)";

      $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

      $stmt->execute(['name' => $name, 'email' => $email, 'message' => $message]);

      var_dump($stmt);

      $status = "Votre message a bien été envoyé";
      $name = "";
      $email = "";
      $message = "";
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: what does the form and inputs look like? Maybe something isn't right in there.

Comment: Please add information on what the `var_dump` calls show?

Comment: When I fill out the form and send, here is the var_damp (stmt) 
After the line : 

` 
$stmt->execute(['name' => $name, 'email' => $email, 'message' => $message]);


//var_dump($stmt);
array(3) { ["name"]=> string(2) "zz" ["email"]=> string(12) "aa@gmail.com" ["message"]=> string(3) "aaa" } object(PDOStatement)#2 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(75) "INSERT INTO contact(name, email, message) VALUES (:name, :email, :message);" }`